# Injective group homomorphism between $D_6$ and $S_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is there an injective group homomorphism  between $D_6$ and $S_5$, where $D_6$ denotes the [dihidral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) of order 12 and $S_5$ the [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)?

Comment: Note that $D_6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$ - are you sure you mean the dihedral group of order $6$ and not $12$.

Comment: @Mark Bennet:There are two "standard" notations for dihedral groups in the market. In one, the index indicates the number of elements of the dihedral group (as in question); in the other, the index indicates the number of vertices of the regular-polygon on which the
dihedral group is acting.

Comment: @user129017 That's why I asked the question - the unedited version said order 6. It is easy to find embeddings of $S_3$ in $S_5$ - so I thought the question probably involved the group of order $12$ which is not so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Recall that $D_{12}\simeq S_3\times Z_2$. First we note that $A_5$ is the symmetries of the icosahedron and that $A_5$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $S_3$ (generated by rotation about a single face, and the other 180 degree rotation so as to to match a face with its opposite face). Now we can get another generator by choosing another odd permutation.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ and $y$ have order $2$, and the product $xy$ has order $n$, then $x$ and $y$ generate a dihedral group with $2n$ elements.  Elements of Sym$(5)$ of order $2$ look like $(ab)$ or $(ab)(cd)$, so with a little calculation you can find $(12)$ and $(23)$ having product $(123)$ of order $3$, so $(12)$ and $(23)$ generate a dihedral subgroup of Sym$(5)$ with $6$ elements.

If you wanted the dihedral group with $12$ elements, $(12)(34)$ and $(45)$ have the product $(12)(345)$ of order $6$, so $(12)(34)$ and $(45)$ generate a dihedral subgroup with $12$ elements.